# Location of my .vimrc file in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I am working on a newly installed Ubuntu system.
I created a my vimrc by typing vim and the then I did :e $MYVIMRC.
I landed up in an empty file, I wrote something this

```
  " Add full file path to your existing statusline
  set statusline+=%F
```

But even after that if I am opening vimrc again by using :e $MYVIMRC its not showing up anything on top as file location path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:help $MYVIMRC` clearly states:

> The $MYVIMRC environment variable is set to the file that was first found, unless $MYVIMRC was already set and when using VIMINIT.

So you can use that to open an **existing** Vim configuration, but not to create it. If you watch closely, you'll see that

```
:e $MYVIMRC
:w
```

will respond with

```
"$MYVIMRC" [New File]
```

So, you've created a file named `$MYVIMRC` in the current directory (as the variable hasn't been set).

---

To create an empty `.vimrc`, just use

```
:e $HOME/.vimrc
```

Since this is a one-time action, all this worrying about the right approach isn't really helpful, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would exit vim, and

```
echo 'set statusline+=%F' > $HOME/.vimrc
```

Comment: This will create a file with the name of .vimrc in my homedirectory but I would like to know the path of that file I created initially.

Comment: @user1590011 You created a file named "$MYVIMRC".

Comment: Using ls -la its not showing that any file by that name exists in my homedirectory

Comment: Did you save with `:w`? I did try it, and it wrote a `\$MYVIMRC`

Comment: If you had opened an existing file, but you just have a blank buffer and it doesn't save (at least here it didn't). Save to a file with `:w`, or open a file.